# Numerical sphere-plane collision resolve

Tags: trigonometry, physics, numerical-calculus

I want to write a c++ program that will calculate collision between sphere and plane.

The rule is that the angle of the falling object equals to angle of reflection.

What do I have for sphere:

```
//sphere coordinates and radius
float x;
float y;
float z;
float r;
//sphere velocity vector projections
float vx;
float vy;
float vz;
```

Plane is described by plane equation coefficients:

```
float A;
float B;
float C;
float D;
```

With sphere-plane collision **detection** I have no problem. But how to find velocity after collision?

[image]

What did I find:

Angle between vector $\vec{(x,y,z)}$ and plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0$:

$$φ =  arcsin(\frac{| A · x + B · y + C · z |}{
\sqrt{A^2 + B^2 + C^2} · \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}})$$

So, ultimately I need to calculate updated values for `vx vy vz`.

Comment: More a physics question. Are the collisions fully elastic?

Comment: @user619894 yes

Answer (score 0):

The velocity vector after the collision is a vector that is reflected around the contact plane. To reflect around a plane with normal $\bf n$, multiply the speed vector by the matrix  $I-\bf 2nn^T$. Are you familiar with matrix and vector notation?

Comment: Thank You for feedback, I have already gotten the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63103362/9430073